# Centos 8 in AWS - PHP install error

Tags: centos, epel

When i try to install PHP with Remi repository i get the below error

```
         dnf module list php
        Remi's Modular repository for Enterprise Linux 8 - aarch64   
        Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'remi-modular':
          - Status code: 403 for http://cdn.remirepo.net/enterprise/8/modular/aarch64/mirror (IP: 176.31.103.194)
          - Status code: 403 for http://cdn.remirepo.net/enterprise/8/modular/aarch64/mirror (IP: 195.154.241.117)
        Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'remi-modular': 
    Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Status code: 403 for
http://cdn.remirepo.net/enterprise/8/modular/aarch64/mirror (IP: 176.31.103.194)
```

If visit the ***page not found*** i get an error called

**Only mirrorlist are served.
Use https://rpms.remirepo.net/ for content.**

Below is how i installed the Remi

```
dnf install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
yum update
dnf install https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-8.rpm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Remi repository packages are currently built only for the x86_64 architecture, and not for aarch64. You will not be able to use remi packages on AWS Graviton instances until Remi chooses to build the packages for the aarch64 architecture.

Comment: DrPixel rebuild some of my RPMs for aarch64, but only for 7, but 8 will probably come later: https://repo.drpixel.fr/

Comment: @RemiCollet You could probably do it yourself without much trouble. I even have a F32 builder on a Raspberry Pi 4 as I only build a few packages.

Comment: See https://github.com/remicollet/remirepo/issues/214 aarch64 is now available for EL-9